# Can I leave Chicago (ORD) on a 10 hour layover

Tags: layovers, chicago, ord

I am traveling from San Francisco to Copenhagen, I have a layover in Chicago for 10 hours. I arrive in Chicago 06:00 am and my next flight is 4 pm London.

Can I leave the airport and will I have enough time to see anything?

Comment: Similar: *[Can I visit Chicago during a 5.5 hour layover in O'Hare?](/questions/4780/)*. For the domestic-to-domestic scenario, see *[Flying from Cedar Rapids to New York via Chicago, don't want to miss the sight seeing of downtown Chicago](/questions/65417)*; for an international-to-international connection, see *[Can I leave O'Hare airport during my layover?](/questions/21064)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you leave the airport? Yes, absolutely, there's nothing stopping you from doing so.

Should you?  With 10 hours, it's feasible provided any luggage is either checked through or you can secure it somehow.

Is 10 hours enough to see anything.  Sure, you have time to see some things but not necessarily do anything like the museums.

You can take the Blue Line from ORD to downtown.  [CTA](http://www.transitchicago.com/) It takes ~45 min.

Warning: 4pm is heading into rush hour leaving the city so plan for extra, extra time getting back to ORD.

Comment: Thank you when you say

"> With 10 hours, it's feasible provided any luggage is either checked through or you can secure it somehow."

The luggage is checked is that something the security does and/or does it require me?

Comment: Checked through means you don't collect it in ORD, the airlines keeps it for the AMS flight.

Comment: Also, watch out for security lines and time to get to the gate (ORD is a big airport). Check how long before the flight you should be at your gate.

Answer (score 2):

There are subways lines that you can get in the airport. 
You can arrive at the Loop in no more than 1 hour. So, you will have enough time to see something.

Comment: Sounds great, so I'm allowed to leave the airport? Without my luggage(with my handbag)? It's my second time flying so sorry if I'm stupid ;)

Comment: You can leave the airport during any connection you want, if you have time.  I once had a beer with a friend in Toronto during a 2-hour connection at Pearson International Airport.